# FlashDevelop - Test IOS on windows - No Devices Detected

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, flashdevelop

I developed an application for mobile, using FlashDevelop's AIR Mobile AS3 App Project template.

Following AIR_Android_readme.txt and AIR_iOS_readme.txt, I successfully packaged it into both apk and ipa.

I can easily test the apk on the computer via bat/RunApp.bat provided by FlashDevelop.

However once I modify RunApp.bat to ios-debug in order to test the ipa, I get the following log in the cmd:

> Packaging application for debugging on iOS -interpreter
>
> Packaging: dist\AppName-debug-interpreter.ipa using certificate:
> cert\iphone_dev.p12...
>
> Installing application for testing on iOS ()
>
> **No Devices Detected**
>
> Installing the app on the device failed
>
> Press any key to continue . .
> .

I have android studio and sdk installed and working, however I didn't install anything similar for IOS development, I have iTunes in case it matters.

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlashDevelop searches for actual devices connected to the computer in order to install the application, I mistook it for an IOS simulator for PC.